# How can I contact a user from this site?

Tags: discussion

Im trying to contact a certain user, I tracked him to two different websites but there is not contact link, nor option to comment.He seems to be expertise in the field of a problem I´m  suffering with Tesseract. May someone help me to reach him?, thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, but no. This is not a social networking site and there is no reason to contact anyone. If you have a question, ask it. If you need clarification, you can leave a comment (once you have [the required reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment)).

No other interaction is supported by the stack exchange sites and this is not likely to change in the foreseeable future. These sites are for asking questions and getting answers not for meeting people.

Comment: Sad,like Ubuntu itself, I hope they improve the site soon. Thank you for your fast answer,kindest regards.

Comment: @Ivan not really. Speaking as an avid user of many SE sites, I am _very_ glad it is not easy for people to contact me directly. If I wanted that to be possible, I would have added my email to my profile as some users do.

Comment: @Ivan It's a feature, not a bug. I've got a few thousand answers out there. It just wouldn't be sustainable for me to field emails on all of them. If you need clarification, leave a comment or ask a separate follow up question (and be sure to link to the original).